# (Java NIO) Should I check both bytes read and buffer position in copying between channels?

Tags: java, nio

This code is similar to example code in the JavaDoc of ByteBuffer.compact()

```java
package com.study.nio;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class BufferCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var from = "Hello World".getBytes();

        var buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);
        buf.clear();
        try (var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             var inChannel = Channels.newChannel(new ByteArrayInputStream(from));
             var outChannel = Channels.newChannel(outputStream);) {
            while (inChannel.read(buf) >= 0 || buf.position() != 0) {
                buf.flip();
                outChannel.write(buf);
                buf.compact();
            }
            System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My question is do we need the **"|| buf.position() !=0"** in the while condition check?

Comment: Yes. It's there for the case where you are getting short writes, so you have something left over in the buffer when you've finished reading.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, the code example provided in the documentation of [Buffer.compact()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact()) is this:

```
   buf.clear();          // Prepare buffer for use
   while (in.read(buf) >= 0 || buf.position != 0) {
       buf.flip();
       out.write(buf);
       buf.compact();    // In case of partial write
   }
```

**Scenario 1: Condition is Finally Met**

- Now, picture the moment when the channel `in` reaches its EOF and it adds its final 100 bytes to the buffer `buff`.
- The code enters the while loop because `in.read(buff) >= 0`, the second condition is not even evaluated.
- Now while writing `out.write(buff)` only 50 of the 100 bytes in the buffer are sent (perhaps the output channel has a very low bandwidth or its buffer is too small).
- The buffer is compacted (pos=50,limit=100,cap=100).
- Now, the while condition is evaluated again, this time `in.read(buff) >= 0` is false because `in` channel is at its EOF, so it evaluates `buf.position != 0` and we discover that there are still bytes in the buffer.
- So, it goes back into the while loop and writes a few more bytes into the output channel.

**Scenario 2: Slow Output Building up**

Another way to look at how this condition gradually builds up is by picturing a scenario when the output channel is slower than the input channel, e.g. low bandwidth and/or a smaller output buffer.

- The code enters the while loop because `in.read(buff) >= 0`, the second condition is not even evaluated. It reads 100 bytes.
- Now while writing `out.write(buff)` only 50 of the 100 bytes in the buffer are sent.
- The buffer is compacted (pos=50,limit=100,cap=100).
- Now, the while condition is evaluated again, and this time `in.read(buff) >= 0` adds 50 more bytes into the buffer and we are once again at 100 bytes total.
- The while repeats in this fashion until the scenario 1 is reached once more `buf.position != 0` is finally evaluated.

Comment: These cases are both the same. There was a short write somewhere, so there was buffer left in the data, so there is something left over to write when you reach end of stream.